# Непонятный отступ над Header

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Не могу сделать нормально обычный шаблон. Отступ сверху появляется.
Непонятно чего так.
Кто знает откуда он? **Что так влияет на него?**

http://jsfiddle.net/XNSZL/

```css
/* СТРУКТУРА */
 html, body, #Container {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#Container {
    min-width:1000px;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
}
#Main {
    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0 0 -100px;
    background:#063;
}
#All {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:100px;
}
#Footer {
    height: 100px;
    background:#699;
}
#Header {
    height:300px;
    margin:0;
    background:#0C9;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
    <div id="Main">
        <div id="All">
            <div id="Header">
                 <h1>HEADER</h1>

            </div>
            <div id="Outer">
                <div id="Inner"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer">
        <div id="FooterContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Убирает если добавить:

```
*{
padding: 0;
margin:0;
}
```

Но интересует, что же это такое...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/XNSZL/1/

```css
/* СТРУКТУРА */
 html, body, #Container {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#Container {
    min-width:1000px;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
}
#Main {
    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0 0 -100px;
    background:#063;
}
#All {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:100px;
}
#Footer {
    height: 100px;
    background:#699;
}
#Header {
    height:300px;
    margin:0;
    background:#0C9;
}
#Header h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
    <div id="Main">
        <div id="All">
            <div id="Header">
                 <h1>HEADER</h1>

            </div>
            <div id="Outer">
                <div id="Inner"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer">
        <div id="FooterContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

нужно занулить margin #Header h1

Comment: Ясно. А почему его margin выходит за пределы родительского элемента?

Comment: так уж марджины работают. вот так не заезжает http://jsfiddle.net/XNSZL/2/ . Нужно просто добавить к хедеру padding-top: 1px;

Comment: Тоже хороший вариант.
А padding у Header как я понимаю не дает margin(у) h1 пройти дальше.
Верно?

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Используйте это

Comment: Типа все обнулить?

Comment: это называется reset

Comment: А когда понадобятся свойства этих элементов,придется все по новой приписывать им?

Comment: Каждый браузер устанавливает свои значения стилей по умолчанию для различных HTML-элементов. С помощью CSS Reset мы можем нивелировать эту разницу для обеспечения кроссбраузерности стилей.

Comment: ага,спасибо. по-изучаю=)

Answer (score 0):

Если писали с нуля, то значения h1-h6 могут сыграть значение.
Обнулив отступы у h1 можно так же убить отсутуп сверху между body и header

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

"hard" reset от soledar10 тоже прикольная вещь)